# Hooking laravel observer in the controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an observer called OfficeUserObserver and it's registered in my provider as well. I want a situation whereby when a user is attached to an office. A mail is automatically sent.
So my observer looks thus:

```js
class OfficeUserObserver
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        dd('hi');
    }

    public function created(OfficeUser $officeUser)
    {
        dd('hi');
    }

    public function saving(OfficeUser $officeUser)
    {
        dd('hi');
    }
 }
```

My Controller looks thus:

```js
public function assignUsers(MyRequest $request, Office $office)
    {
        ...
        $office->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($users);
    }
```

When I however try to attach a user to an office. The process is successful but nothing ever gets dumped(dd()) on my view despite using dd() in my construct. What am I doing wrong please?

Here is the code in my AppServiceProvider

```js
public function boot()
    {
        OfficeUser::observe(OfficeUserObserver::class);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use UserObserver you should use pivot models for relations.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

```php
class UserOffice extends Model {...}
```

And observers will work for the pivot model, but not for `User` or `Office`.

Or use package for relation events:
https://github.com/chelout/laravel-relationship-events

P.S.: Sorry for disinformation in the previous edit.